# Installation and movement of elements

Tags: reactjs, canvas, konva

How to implement moving and installing an object so that it is installed at full width? Example of implementation (https://s-kupe.by/index.php/konstruktor-shkafov-kupe-onlajn).

I just started studying and my task is to make a cabinet designer and I want to start with installing partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a library like [React-Grid-Layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-layout/v/1.4.1). It allows you to create flexible and responsive grid-based layouts, where components can be moved and arranged in rows and columns. You can refer to the documentation here: https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-grid-layout#react-grid-layout
and try out the demos here: https://react-grid-layout.github.io/react-grid-layout/examples/0-showcase.html

You can set the grid layout parameter sizes to fix your required cabinet length/height and customise the grids' appearance to be your partitions.

Comment: I will still need to show the dimensions of the cabinet, Canvas has more options for this, I also found how the division was done using the example of a window, I need to understand how to add DnD.(https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/konvajs/site/tree/master /react-demos/window-frame-design-app?hidenavigation=1&view=split&fontsize=10)